# red cut layer over the UILabel text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I m using `UILabel` to show the product price. Now in time of offer price I have to show the price like the `image` as

[image]

Don't know how to do the things, any idea can help me a lot. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If your app is for iOS >= 6.0, then use [`NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

2) If your app is supported to older versions means less than 6.0 then my suggestion is to take one more `label` or `view` with required `height, width & background color`. Add that `label` on your `view` above the price `label`.